# JSTL gets "stuck" using one language version of resource bundle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, internationalization, jstl

Problem: JSTL gets "stuck" using one language version of a resource bundle when I believe it should be toggling between them; not just for one session, but also new sessions. Struts `bean:message` tags on the same page use the same resource bundles and toggle language as expected.

It's irrelevant (I think?) to the question, but a Struts1 Action checks if a parameter was passed in the URL to toggle the language between English and French.

```
String localeSwitch = request.getParameter("locale");
if (localeSwitch != null) {
    if (localeSwitch.equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage(), Locale.CANADA.getCountry());
        request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
        Config.set(request.getSession(), Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
    } else if (localeSwitch.equalsIgnoreCase("fr")) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(Locale.FRENCH.getLanguage(), Locale.CANADA.getCountry());
        request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
        Config.set(request.getSession(), Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
    }
}
```

`Config.FMT_LOCALE` is for JSTL, `Globals.LOCALE_KEY` is for Struts.

In the JSP (because I'm really confused), I have:

```
<%
out.println("Config.FMT_LOCALE="+Config.get(request.getSession(), Config.FMT_LOCALE));
%>
<fmt:bundle basename="proj.resources.Resource">
    <fmt:message var="mymessage" key="mymessage" />
</fmt:bundle>
${mymessage}
<%
out.println("Config.FMT_LOCALE="+Config.get(request.getSession(), Config.FMT_LOCALE));
%>
```

The resource files are called `Resource.properties` and `Resource_fr.properties`.

Between each of the following, the application server (JBoss) was restarted:

- (Expected behaviour) Access page without specifying language: `Config.FMT_LOCALE=null` output,
  English message is displayed.
- (Expected behaviour) Access page specifying English: `Config.FMT_LOCALE=en_CA` output, English
  message is displayed.
- (Expected behaviour) Access page specifying French: `Config.FMT_LOCALE=fr_CA` output, French
  message is displayed.
- (Unxpected behaviour) Access page without specifying language, then access page specifying French:
  `Config.FMT_LOCALE=fr_CA` output, English message is displayed.
- (Unxpected behaviour) Access page specifying English, then access page specifying French:
  `Config.FMT_LOCALE=fr_CA` output, English message is displayed.
- (Unxpected behaviour) Access page specifying French, then access page specifying English:
  `Config.FMT_LOCALE=en_CA` output, English message is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been caused by the JARs packaged with Struts that also do JSTL: jstl-1.0.2.jar and standard-1.0.2.jar.

Changing my build file to exclude these when creating the WAR file (resulting in the JBoss jstl.jar being used) corrected the problem.